# How to load dynamically KML file to google maps and further to polyline?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, polyline

I could not find the answer, how to load dynamically on the map KML file using input file? Important is that this operations should be done only on client side without uploading to server whether it is possible using JavaScript? As a result JavaScript should extract only the coordinates and insert them into polyline but it is a matter of secondary.

My current concept: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vVLWg/3/)

I found an interesting example, but here's a copy/paste and api v2: [link](http://display-kml.appspot.com/)

Maybe to insert to polyline loaded kml this: [link](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) parser would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the File API in HTML 5. It now allows reading the content of a local file. Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Unfortunately some browsers don't support it, but it's the only way I know of outside of using flash or java. Once you have the KML file contents in Javascript, you can use the [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) parser you referenced to parse the data and display on your map.

Comment: Thanks very nice tutorial but I learned that my browser don't support FileReader let alone about older now I think I'll read the file via copy paste into a text box and parse it into the map.